# Move svn repositories

Tags: linux, svn

I have multiple svn repositories on my vServer :

```
/development
  |...../kooki
          |_...../svn
                   |_...../repo1
                   |_...../repo2
                   |_...../repo3
```

now I only want to change the location to another folder e.g. :

```
/development
  |...../a_new_folder
          |_...../svn
                   |_...../repo1
                   |_...../repo2
                   |_...../repo3
```

You see, the old structure is the same.
Can I simply use

```
cp -R /development/kooki /development/a_new_folder
```

or is a svndump needed?

Thanks kooki

Comment: I would suggest to consider switching to `git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But in any case you have to change config of server (if svn:// of http:// access used) and reflect moved root in server's config (`-root` for svnserver, `SVNParentPath` for Apache)